# Node implementation & DynamoDB Encryption At Rest

Tags: node.js, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

I've created a DynamoDB table - Encryption is enabled at its configuration.
Added some sample records and tried to retrieve it from my node application.

Once the records are retrieved, I can see it in plain text. Shouldn't it be encrypted?

My apologies if my question sounds stupid :)

Comment: That's a really old question I know, yet it seems wrong to leave it like this. So my guess is, that encryption at rest means the data is encrypted on the drives and DynamoDB handles encryption and decryption for you. Otherwise how would you decrypt data you havent encrypted nor have any key?

Comment: Some AWS info on it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.howitworks.html